# How to fix a branch rebased onto a commit amend, which has resulted in a "rebase in progress"?

Tags: git, merge

I'm relatively new to git, so detail would be appreciated. Please point out if I am doing something completely wrong.

So here's what the problem looks like:

1. I downloaded from remote, which only had the one branch, master.
2. I made a commit to master
3. I pushed the change after rebasing master onto a newly fetched origin/master (the change has still not been merged into remote though)
4. I made a new branch from master called bug1 and made some changes
5. I pushed bug1 after rebasing to origin/master after a fetch (this change is not yet merged to remote)
6. I made a branch from master, called bug2.
7. I amended my most recent commit on master (with required information that would be useful to bug2)
8. I checked out bug2, and did `git rebase master`, hoping that all the changes that were done in master would be reflected now in bug2.
9. I believe, from observation, that my goal was indeed achieved, the work on master was now in bug2.
10. What's weird is, when I do git status, I get this:

```sh
rebase in progress; onto ec578ba
You are currently rebasing branch 'bug2' on 'ec578ba'.
  (fix conflicts and then run "git rebase --continue")
  (use "git rebase --skip" to skip this patch)
  (use "git rebase --abort" to check out the original branch)

Unmerged paths:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
  (use "git add <file>..." to mark resolution)

    both modified:   c.py
    both modified:   f.py
    both modified:   s.py

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

    modified:   t.py
    modified:   co.txt
    modified:   h.py

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

    blablaa.pyc

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

Also, git branch -a shows:

```sh
* (no branch, rebasing bug2)
  bug1
  bug2
  master
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  remotes/origin/master
```

I don't really know what I did wrong... I thought it would all work out from what I learnt online, but clearly I need to do some "merging" to fix this problem...

Can someone help?
Thank you so much! This seems like way too specific a problem too Google, I don't even know the right terms I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really are in the middle of a rebase, just as `git status` says.  (If your Git version is 2.0 or higher `git status` is pretty good and reliable; there were some major improvements in the 1.7 and 1.8 releases so if you have a truly ancient `git status`, you should still use it, but it's not as good as a modern Git.)

The reason you're stuck in a merge is that `git commit --amend` is kind of a white lie: it doesn't actually *change* an existing commit.  Instead, it makes a new and improved commit, then says: *Let's use this one instead of the old one.*  Unfortunately, any branch that already has and depends on the old one, still has the old one.

Let's go through these in detail:

> 1. I downloaded from remote, which only had the one branch, master.

I am going to assume that you mean you ran:

```
git clone <url>
cd <new-clone>
```

here.

> 2. I made a commit to master

Hence:

```
<edit some file>
git add <that file>
git commit
```

Let's back off a bit here now, and describe what a commit is and does, with a quick dive into *how* it does it as well.  (There will be a lot here, but you can just kind of remember that there was a lot, and come back to it later when that's appropriate.)

#### Commits and branch names

Every commit you make has a full snapshot of all of your files.  These files are frozen for all time: they cannot be changed.  The commit also has a bit of *metadata*, such as your name and email address, the date-and-time stamp of *when* you made the commit, and *why* you made the commit—your log message.  Git hardly makes any use of the log message, so you can put in anything you like, but the point of a log message is to remind yourself (or someone else) not so much *what* you did—Git can show that to you on its own—but rather *why* you did it, i.e., something that just the change itself *can't* show.

Each commit has its own unique hash ID.  The hash ID is a big ugly string like `83232e38648b51abbcbdb56c94632b6906cc85a6`; these show up a lot of places, including `git log` output, sometimes in abbreviated form (`83232e3` and the like).  The hash ID is the real "true name" of the commit, and is how Git *finds* the commit: Git needs to have the hash ID in its gitty little paws, in order to extract the commit.  So if it were not for branch names, you'd be jotting these things down on paper all the time, or something—but that's silly, we have a computer, we can just have *it* jot them down in a file, or something.

That's what a branch name is and does: it's a file, or a line in a file, or something, that remembers a hash ID.  In fact, it remembers only *one* hash ID: the hash ID of the *last* commit in the branch.  But that's OK, because each commit *also* remembers a hash ID.  Specifically, each commit remembers the hash ID of the commit that comes just before it, which Git calls the *parent*.  So we end up with:

```
... <-F <-G <-H   <--branch
```

with the uppercase letters standing in for the real hash IDs.  The *name*, `branch`, holds the hash ID of the last commit `H`.  `H` itself holds the hash ID of an earlier commit `G`, which holds the hash ID of `F`, and so on.  This allows Git to walk backwards through the series of commits.

To make a *new* branch, you simply pick some existing commit and attach a name to it:

```
...--F--G   <-- newbranch
         \
          H   <-- master
```

or:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- newbranch, master
```

Now that you have more than one name, Git needs a way to know *which* name you're using.  That's where `HEAD` comes in:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- newbranch (HEAD), master
```

means that the current name is `newbranch` (and the current commit is `H`).

Remember that we noted that files in commits are frozen for all time.  They're all read-only.  They're also compressed, so as to take less space.  I like to call these *freeze-dried*.  Being frozen like this, if you have many commits that keep re-using most of the same files, Git can and does actually just re-use the already-frozen files.  That's one of several tricks Git has up its sleeves to keep the repository from growing fast, even though every commit saves every file.  But, while this is great for archival, it's obviously quite useless for getting any new work done.  You need files that you can read and write.  So `git checkout` *extracts* a commit, which becomes your *current* commit, and gets all its freeze-dried files rehydrated into in your *work-tree*.  Here, your files have their ordinary everyday format.  You can use them and work with them.

Git could stop here—with the frozen committed files, one particularly interesting set of frozen files being those in the current commit, and the usable set in the work-tree—and other version control systems do stop here.  But for various reasons, Git hides a *third* copy of your files, kind of in between the frozen set and the usable set.  These copies are in Git's *index* or *staging area*—these are two names for the same thing.  What's in the index is in the freeze-dried format.  But unlike an actual commit, *these* files can be replaced at any time, or have new file added or have files removed.

Whenever you make a new commit, what Git really does is package the pre-freeze-dried *index* copies into a commit.  This goes very fast and does not have to—and does not—use what's in your work-tree at all!  So you first have to make Git update its index, which is what `git add` is about.  The `git add` command freeze-dries a work-tree file and overwrites the copy in the index, or if the file wasn't in the index before, creates it there.

Having packaged up the files, and added your name and log message and so on, Git sets the parent of the *new* commit to be the *current* commit.  Then it writes the new commit into the all-commits database:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- newbranch (HEAD), master
            \
             I
```

Now that the commit is there, the last step for `git commit` is to make the *name*, in this case `newbranch`, point to commit `I` instead of commit `H`:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- master
            \
             I   <-- newbranch (HEAD)
```

#### Although commits are snapshots, Git can show changes

If you ask Git to show you commit `I`, or commit `H` for that matter, Git *could* just show you all the files that are in it.  But that's not usually want we want to know.  For commit `H`, we'd like to know: *What's **different** in `H` than in `G`?*  So when `git log -p` or `git show` shows commit `H`, it actually looks at both `G` *and* `H`.  Whatever files are different, Git compares the two files and tells you what changed.  When looking at commit `I`, Git compares the snapshots in `H` and `I` and tells you what's changed.

This is a general theme: for any commit with just one parent, Git can easily extract *both* the parent *and* the commit and compare the two.  That turns a commit into a set of changes.  It's important to remember that this requires choosing a *previous* commit.  Git will then compare the two snapshots.  It's just that, for most commits, the choice is so obvious that we don't have to name it at all.

#### Back to your steps

So, this gets us back to step 2: you added a new commit to `master`.  Let's draw that this way:

```
             I   <-- master (HEAD)
            /
...--F--G--H   <-- origin/master
```

(`origin/master` is your Git's method of remembering where `master` is, or was, in the Git repository you cloned earlier).

> 3. I pushed the change after rebasing master onto a newly fetched origin/master (the change has still not been merged into remote though)

That is, you ran:

```
git fetch origin              # or just `git fetch`, which does the same thing
git rebase origin/master      # or `git pull --rebase origin master`
git push origin master
```

Assuming no one added any new commits to the Git repository at `origin`, the rebase step did nothing.  The last step, though, `git push origin master`, does something important:

- Your Git calls up the Git at `origin`
- Your Git finds out which commits they have (by hash ID).
- Your Git offers any *new* commits you have that they don't, which is commit `I`, also by hash ID.
- Your Git ends the `git push` session with a request to them: *Hey, other Git, please set your `master` to point to commit `I`.*

If they obey this request—and there's no reason listed here that they shouldn't—they'll end up with:

```
...--F--G--H--I   <-- master
```

in *their* repository.  Your Git will see that they accepted the request and will update your `origin/master` to match, so we can straighten out the kink in the drawing of *your* repository's contents and list them as:

```
...--F--G--H--I   <-- master (HEAD), origin/master
```

You added:

> (the change has still not been merged into remote though)

but that's not relevant: it's neither true nor false as there's nothing to *merge;* but they *do* have your new commit `I` and their `master` points to `I`.

> I made a new branch from master called bug1 and made some changes

So you ran, e.g.:

```
git checkout -b bug1
```

which added a new branch label `bug1` pointing to commit `I` and made that `HEAD`:

```
...--F--G--H--I   <-- bug1 (HEAD), master, origin/master
```

and then you modified some file(s), ran `git add`, and ran `git commit` to make a new commit `J`:

```
...--F--G--H--I   <-- master, origin/master
               \
                J   <-- bug1 (HEAD)
```

> 5. I pushed bug1 after rebasing to origin/master after a fetch (this change is not yet merged to remote)

Again, the "not yet merged" is pretty much meaningless: your Git called up their Git, offered them your commit `J`, and asked them to create their name `bug1` pointing to commit `J`.  There's no question of *merging* during any `git push`: it's all just a matter of whether they accept your requests to change or create some branch name(s).  So they just have two branch names now, `master` pointing to `I` and `bug1` pointing to `J`.  Your own Git then says to itseif: *Ah, they accepted the request to create `bug1` so I will now remember that they have a `bug1` pointing to commit `J`.*  This means your own repository can now be drawn as:

```
...--F--G--H--I   <-- master, origin/master
               \
                J   <-- bug1 (HEAD), origin/bug1
```

> 6. I made a branch from master, called bug2.

That is:

```
git checkout -b bug2 master
```

or equivalent.  This selects commit `I` as the *current* commit and makes a new name for it, extracting the contents of `I` into your index and work-tree, and attaching `HEAD` to the new name:

```
...--F--G--H--I   <-- bug2 (HEAD), master, origin/master
               \
                J   <-- bug1, origin/bug1
```

(If you used `git branch`, that didn't adjust `HEAD` and you might still be on commit `J`, but otherwise it works pretty much the same way.)

> 7. I amended my most recent commit on master (with required information that would be useful to bug2)

So:

```
git checkout master
```

This step selects commit `I` as the current commit and attaches `HEAD` to the name `master`.  If necessary, your index and work-tree get adjusted to match `I`, but if you're already on `I` there's no work here; the end result is:

```
...--F--G--H--I   <-- bug2, master (HEAD), origin/master
               \
                J   <-- bug1, origin/bug1
```

So here, the only real change was to change which name `HEAD` was attached-to, unless you were on commit `J`, which case it also checked out commit `I`.  Then you did:

```
<make some changes and run git add>
git commit --amend
```

The `--amend` option doesn't actually *change* commit `I` at all.  Instead, it makes a new, different commit.  We could call it `I'` (to reflect that it's a copy of `I`) or just give it a whole new letter `K`.  I'll do the latter here.  The tricky part of `git commit --amend` is that instead of pointing back to `I`, the new commit points back to `I`'s *parent* `H`:

```
             K   <-- master (HEAD)
            /
...--F--G--H--I   <-- bug2, origin/master
               \
                J   <-- bug1, origin/bug1
```

Note that commit `I` still exists, and is still remembered via both `bug2` and `origin/master`.  The Git repository over on `origin` still has commit `I`; it still remembers commit `I` through its `master`.  Your own `bug1` remembers commit `J` which remembers commit `I`, and the Git over on origin also has `J` (which necessarily remembers `I`—the *commits* are identical in every Git repository that has them).

You can, locally, trace who has what by looking at all of your own branch names—`bug1`, `bug2`, and `master`—and walking backwards, one commit at a time, to see which commits *you* can reach.  Do the same with your remote-tracking names `origin/bug1` and `origin/master` to see which commits you have that *they* can reach.<sup>1</sup>

Now we get to the problematic step:

> 8. I checked out bug2, and did `git rebase master`, hoping that all the changes that were done in master would be reflected now in bug2.

Now we have to look at what rebase does—but in short, it *copies* commits, as if by `git cherry-pick`.  The commits it copies are based on the arguments you give it.

---

<sup>1</sup>At least, this is what they have *to the best of your own Git's knowledge*.  It hasn't called up the other Git in more than three *seconds*, and who knows how much it might have changed in all that time!  This is where may be important to know who's changing the upstream Git repository.  How fast does it get updated?

---

#### Which commits a rebase copies

Let's go back to the graph, adjusted for `git checkout bug2`:

```
             K   <-- master
            /
...--F--G--H--I   <-- bug2 (HEAD), origin/master
               \
                J   <-- bug1, origin/bug1
```

and to the command:

```
git rebase master
```

Here, you've used the simplest form of `git rebase`.  You can use `git rebase --onto` to separate the rebase target—*where to put the copies*, more or less—from the *limiter*, i.e., *what **not** to copy*.  With the simplest form, the two are the same thing: `master` is both *where to put the copies* and *what not to copy*.

Git will now start at `bug2` and walk backwards through the graph, listing commits.  These are `I`, then `H`, then `G`, and so on.  It will also start at `master` and walk backwards, listing commits: `K`, then `H`, then `G`, and so on.  Whatever is in the *second* list gets *excluded*.<sup>2</sup>  So that leaves commit `I`.

The resulting list is the list of commits to copy (in the wrong order, so Git will reverse the list, but here there's only one entry).  Rebase will now try to copy commit `I` to come after commit `K`.  The exact mechanism of the copying is a bit complicated—some `git rebase` operations actually run `git cherry-pick` and some don't—but it's meant to have the same outcome either way, and work *like* `git cherry-pick`.  This essentially means *merge the changes that someone made in the `H`-vs-`I` path with the changes someone made in the `H`-vs-`K` path*.

Of course, that "someone" was *you*.  These changes conflicted with each other.  Git was not able to resolve the conflicts on its own.  Had Git been able to resolve the conflicts on its own, Git would have tried to make a new commit—a copy of `I`, except that the new commit's parent would be `K`—and it would then be done and would set the name `bug` to point to the new commit.  Since it's a copy of `I` (but didn't actually happen) let's call it `I'` just to show what things would look like if it *did* happen:

```
               I'  <-- bug2 (HEAD)
              /
             K   <-- master
            /
...--F--G--H--I   <-- origin/master
               \
                J   <-- bug1, origin/bug1
```

You could resolve the conflicts by choosing all the files from commit `K`, i.e., dropping all the changes from `H`-vs-`I` that aren't already in `H`-vs-`K` and just keeping what's in `K`.  But then there's no real point in bothering with a new commit at all: just make the name `bug2` point directly to commit `K`, like this:

```
             K   <-- bug2 (HEAD), master
            /
...--F--G--H--I   <-- origin/master
               \
                J   <-- bug1, origin/bug1
```

You *can* do this with `git rebase`, you just need the longer form:

```
git rebase --onto master <anything that specifies commit I>
```

The `--onto master` tells Git: *put the copies after the commit identified by `master`*, i.e., after `K`, and the rest tells Git: *don't copy commit `I`, nor anything earlier*.  So that would do the job: it would copy *no* commits, then move the name `bug2`.

It's simpler, in this case, to just move the name `bug2` yourself.  That's particularly easy *because* you never used `git push` to tell any *other* Git to make the name `bug2` remember anything.  So no one else needs to be told: *Oh, hey, the `bug2` I asked you to make?  Forget about it, use this instead.*

However, you *do* have a problem with `master` and with `bug1`.  You've told some other Git—the one at `origin`—to remember commit `I` as their `master`, and commit `J` as their `bug1`.  They presumably still remember those.  You can tell that other Git: *Here's commit `K`.  And, oh, hey, that commit `I` you're remembering as your `master` ... remember new commit `K` as your `master`.*  That requires a *force push*, `git push -f` or `git push --force-with-lease`.  You also have to do something about your own `bug1`, such as use `git rebase --onto` to copy commit `J` to a new and improved commit that comes after `K`, and then call up the Git over at `origin`, send them the new and improved commit, and force them to move *their* `bug1` too.

#### What to do now

First, though, you need to get out of rebase hell. :-)  The easy way to do that is to use:

```
git rebase --abort
```

which puts everything back the way it was before you started.  That is, you're now back to:

```
             K   <-- master
            /
...--F--G--H--I   <-- bug2 (HEAD), origin/master
               \
                J   <-- bug1, origin/bug1
```

Now you can do one (or more) of many things.  Here are two straightforward options:

- `git checkout -B bug2 master`, or
- `git checkout master; git branch -D bug2; git checkout -b bug2`

These result in:

```
             K   <-- bug2 (HEAD), master
            /
...--F--G--H--I   <-- origin/master
               \
                J   <-- bug1, origin/bug1
```

You can now go on to work on `bug2`.

At some point—any time now or later—you can run:

```
git push --force-with-lease origin master
```

which has your Git call up their Git, offer them your new commit `K`, and tell them: *I think your `master` points to commit `I`.  If so, make it point to commit `K` instead.*<sup>2</sup>  This is very similar to `--force` / `-f`, except that a plain force just sends them a command: *Set your `master`!*  If someone else, presumably not you, has added *more* commits past `I`, you'll cause the Git at `origin` to *lose* those commits.  In this case you *want* their `master` to "lose" commit `I`: it's been replaced with new-and-improved `K`.

Then, eventually, you'll probably also want to:

```
git checkout bug1
git rebase --onto master bug1~1
```

This special bit of syntax—`bug1~1`—tells Git: *Starting at `bug1`, work backwards through one commit.*  That is, it finds `bug1` (commit `J`) and then steps back one step to commit `I`.  These are the commits *not* to copy—`I` and anything earlier—so `git rebase` will now copy `J`, by doing the `I`-vs-`J` comparison, and adding those changes to come after whatever commit is at the tip of `master`.  If you've made a few `bug2` commits but no new `master` ones, and forced `origin/master` to remember `K`, that might now look like this:

```
               L--M   <-- bug2
              /
             K   <-- master, origin/master
            / \
...--F--G--H   J'   <-- bug1 (HEAD)
            \
             I
              \
               J   <-- origin/bug1
```

Now that you've replaced `J` with new-and-improved `J'`, you can tell the Git over at `origin` that it's OK to forget all about `I` and `J`: they should set *their* `bug1` to remember `J'` instead:

```
git push --force-with-lease origin bug1
```

or of course the simpler `git push -f origin bug1`, which just *assumes* their `bug1` points to `J` and makes them forget the `I-J` part and just remember `J'`.

---

<sup>2</sup>The `--force-with-lease` option has to tell the other Git: *I think your name <name> points to commit <oldhash>.  If so, set it to <newhash>.*  The place it gets this information is the same as always: your Git has your `origin/master`, remembering where your Git saw their Git's `master` the last time you ran `git fetch`, or succeeded with a `git push origin master`.  So if the name to update is `master`, the old hash is from your own `origin/master`; if the name to update is `bug1`, the old hash is from your own `origin/bug1`.